# Spring 3.2 and Jackson 2: add custom object mapper

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm developing a REST webservice in spring MVC. I need to change how jackson 2 serialize mongodb objectids. I'm not sure of what to do because I found partial documentation for jackson 2, what I did is to create a custom serializer:

```
public class ObjectIdSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ObjectId> {


    @Override
    public void serialize(ObjectId value, JsonGenerator jsonGen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGen.writeString(value.toString());
    }
}
```

Create a ObjectMapper

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("ObjectIdmodule");
        module.addSerializer(ObjectId.class, new ObjectIdSerializer());
        this.registerModule(module);
    }

}
```

and then register the mapper

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper">
                <bean class="my.package.CustomObjectMapper"></bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

My CustomConverter is never called. I think the CustomObjectMapper definition is wrong,I adapted it from some code for jackson 1.x

In my controllers I'm using @ResponseBody.
Where am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Serializer and registration look correct to me, so I think the problem lies in xml configuration.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the suggestion, I had an empty <mvc:annotation-driven> tag around the file. It's working now

Comment: FYI the docs say to use StdSerializer instead: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/StdSerializer.html

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  Can you please post your final working solution?

Comment: In my project we extends StdSerializer instead of JsonSerializer, but that is not the problem. Be sure that you use com.fasterxml.* classes and not old org.codehaus.* classes?

Comment: Try changing `register-defaults="true"` to `register-defaults="false"`

Comment: @alex, can you please post the total solution?

Comment: This is the code i used https://gist.github.com/alexmazza/f61aa2a72e9f725c2ef8 It's basically the same that I posted here, the problem was in the xml configuration, I had a double <mvc:annotation-driven> tag that was messing things

Answer (score 4):

You should annotate corresponding model field with [@JsonSerialize](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) annontation. In your case it may be:

```
public class MyMongoModel{
   @JsonSerialize(using=ObjectIdSerializer.class)
   private ObjectId id;
}
```

But in my opinion, it should better don't use entity models as VOs. Better way is to have different models and map between them.
You can find [my example project here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8wdswdvq82j1s76/jackson-example.tar.gz?dl=0) (I used date serialization with Spring 3 and Jackson 2 as example).

Answer (score 0):

How I would do this is:

Create an annotation to declare your custom serializers:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyMessageConverter{
}
```

Set up component scan for this in your mvcconfiguration file

```
<context:include-filter expression="package.package.MyMessageConverter"
            type="annotation" />
```

and create a class that implements `HttpMessageConverter<T>`.

```
@MyMessageConverter
public MyConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<T>{
//do everything that's required for conversion.
}
```

Create a class that `extends AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter implements InitializingBean`.

```
    public MyAnnotationHandler extends AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter implements InitializingBean{
    //Do the stuffs you need to configure the converters
    //Scan for your beans that have your specific annotation
    //get the list of already registered message converters
    //I think the list may be immutable. So, create a new list, including all of the currently configured message converters and add your own. 
    //Then, set the list back into the "setMessageConverters" method.
    }
```

I believe this is everything that is required for your goal.

Cheers.

Comment: I believe the way that you're going about this, is more of the "Jersey way".

Comment: This answer has so much unnecessary complexity. OP is doing it the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create object mapper. Add jackson-core-2.0.0.jar and jackson-annotations-2.0.0.jar to your project.

Now, add the following lines of code to your controller while handing the service:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "students", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json", consumes = "application/json")

public HashMap<String, String> postStudentForm(
            @RequestBody Student student, HttpServletResponse response)
```

Do not miss any of the annotations.