# How to apply property editors on the objects being returned in response to ajax calls?

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am specifying the property editors for my controller as :

```
@InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
    }
```

which work fine until I call the following method in an AJAX call.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "searchCriteria", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Set<SearchCriteria> loadSearchCriterias(){
        // call service method to load criterias
        Set<SearchCriteria> criterias = new HashSet<SearchCriteria>();
        SearchCriteria sampleCriteria = new SearchCriteria();
        sampleCriteria.setStartDate(new Date());
                criterias.add(sampleCriteria);
        return criterias;
         }
```

In this case, the due date in `SearchCriteria` is not being converted to the proper format by the custom property editor. How can I make property editors to be applied even when I am returning an object through an AJAX call ?

```
public class SearchCriteria{
    Date startDate;
    String name;
    // getter setters
}
```

Comment: You need to use jackson serializers for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to apply property editor for the returned values. Spring has a converter mechanism for it.

If you returning `json` and if you have [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) in your classpath then spring will use it to convert the object to response string.
If you returning `xml` and if you have [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) in your classpath then spring will use it to convert the object to response string.

If you are using `Jackson` library with spring then you need to tell jackson how you want to serialize the field by using [serializer](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers).

Ex:

```
public class DateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        if (value != null) {
            SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            jgen.writeString(f.format(value));
        }
    }

}
```

Then annotate your field like

```
@JsonSerialize(using = DateTimeSerializer.class)
private Date createdDate;
```

If you want to use this globally you can try the mechanism explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363555/spring-3-2-and-jackson-2-add-custom-object-mapper).

Comment: Thanks, but how to configure the jackson serializer for use with this class ?

Comment: can you share your `SearchCriteria`?

Comment: added the class. I guess adding the annotation to the createdDate field will automatically force Spring to search for the DateTimeSerializer anywhere in the classpath (or do we have to specify it somewhere ?)